# Splunk custom RUM data with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, splunk, open-telemetry

I am trying to send custom RUM data to Splunk. I am referring [ManualInstrumentation](https://github.com/signalfx/splunk-otel-js-web/blob/main/docs/ManualInstrumentation.md). As I have front-end in *Angularjs* so not able to import *trace* from *opentelemetry/api*. Is there any *.js* file for *opentelemetry/api* like [splunk-otel-web.js](https://cdn.signalfx.com/o11y-gdi-rum/latest/splunk-otel-web.js) so that I can use *trace* directly.

Comment: Just curious, why doesn't importing trace work?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I am not able to import `trace` because I have a front-end in `Angularjs-v1.2.20` & don't have `node_modules`, all required js libraries are imported in the `vendor` folder under `webapp` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved... I don't have to go for `opentelemetry/api` as I am able to fetch `tracer` from `splunk-otel-web.js` using the following code syntax:

```
const span = SplunkRum.provider.getTracer('searchbox').startSpan('search');
span.setAttribute('searchLength', searchString.length);
// time passes
span.end();
```